# Reset button on NSTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have an NSTimer and I need a reset button that resets the variable on screen and stops that timer until it is started agin by the start button. Here's some code:

```
@implementation TimeController

int timeTick = 0;


NSTimer *timer;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    labelTime.text = @"0";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:(self) selector:(@selector(tick)) userInfo:(nil) repeats:(YES)];
}

- (IBAction)resetTicktock:(id)sender {
    [timer invalidate];

}

-(void)tick{
    timeTick++;
    NSString *timeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", timeTick];
    labelTime.text = timeString;



}


@end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are `timeTick` and `timer` declared where they are? Why aren't these ivars instead of global variables?

Comment: Isn't your code working? It looks like ok, Are you facing any problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a function started already to stop the timer. Just reset the variable there.

```
- (IBAction)resetTicktock:(id)sender {
    [timer invalidate];
    labelTime.text = @"0";
}
```

Link your button to this method in your storyboard for the action "Touch Up Inside".

Answer (score 0):

You need reset the timeTick and the the text of label

```
- (IBAction)resetTicktock:(id)sender {
   [timer invalidate];
   labelTime.text = @"0";
   timeTick = 0;
}
```